# Can't reach website hosted on ubuntu with nginx

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx

OS: Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx version: 1.14.0, Asp.net version: core 3.1

Long story short:

1. Can't hit port 5001 from outside of the linux box. But can hit it inside of it.
2. Nginx is passing through the request, but it doesn't hit the web app.
3. Another website on same server under same nginx is working.

After a deployment it stopped working. when I visit the https://example.com, Nginx issues a 307 redirect to https://www.example.com:5001/. And my browser cannot reach it, saying "It looks like [www.mywsite.com](http://www.mywsite.com) closed the connection". The deployment only changed

```
wget https://localhost:5001 --no-check-certificate
```

So it seems to the web application will respond to requests made to port 5001. But somehow the request was not going from Nginx to the application.

Another website hosted on the same server (listening on port 5050) with Nginx with almost identical configuration is working just fine with browser(receives code 200 instead of 307).

I have rebooted the webserver, restarted the dotnet web application, reloaded nginx. Nothing worked.

Here is the nginx configuration for "mysite":

```
server {
    
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://mysite;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        root /var/www/mysite/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

upstream mysite{
    zone dotnet 64k;
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    listen *:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

When I listed all the listening services by dotnet, interestingly the working website only listening on 5050:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1654/dotnet
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5510/dotnet
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5510/dotnet
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40678         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 1654/dotnet
>
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:5050                :::*                    LISTEN      1654/dotnet
>
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:5000                :::*                    LISTEN      5510/dotnet
>
> tcp6       0      0 ::1:5001                :::*                    LISTEN      5510/dotnet

Tail from nginx access.log:

> (my IPv4 address) - - [05/May/2021:15:37:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46"

Tail from nginx error.log ( I do find some entries from several hours ago, but recent failures did not create entries):

> 2021/05/05 12:03:11 [error] 5481#5481: *187 upstream prematurely
> closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
> {my IPv4 address}               26, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: "example.com"

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share tail of the error and access logs.

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili I have added log entries. Thank you for asking.

Comment: You are telling the 5001 port is listening, but I can't find the related configuration in your nginx conf. Are you sure 5001 port is listening?

Comment: The last access log is telling the request is redirected successfully, but the redirected request is not logged. I expected to see that request after the presented log.

Answer (score 1):

In your config, I only see 3 areas where you are setting a listen directive. First the 443 globs on all interfaces per default "listen 443 ssl". Then you direct it to listen on 127.0.0.1 on port 5000, and then you later glob on port 80. In none of that are you telling it to listen on port 5001, but maybe nginx does that automagically? If so, then likely your "listen 127.0.0.1:5000" should be "listen *:5000" so it globs on all of your interfaces (ipv4 and ipv6).